# Dispatch co-variant list elements according to subclass

Tags: c#, dynamic, dispatch, contravariance

I have classes `B` and `C`, inheriting from class `SuperA`. If I have a list of `SuperA` containing various implementations of `SuperA`, how can I call method taking `B` and `C` argument according to the actual implementation of each element in the list, without having to test the type of each element (I would prefer to avoid `if(item is B)` stuff for open/closed principle reasons).

```
public class Test
{
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        var list = new List<SuperA> {new B(), new C()};

        var factory = new OutputFactory();

        foreach (SuperA item in list)
        {
            DoSomething(factory.GenerateOutput(item)); // doesn't compile as there is no GenerateOutput(SuperA foo) signature in OutputFactory.
        }
    }

    private static void DoSomething(OutputB b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());
    }

    private static void DoSomething(OutputC c)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(c.ToString());
    }

    public class SuperA
    {
    }

    public class B : SuperA
    {
    }

    public class C : SuperA
    {
    }


    public class OutputB
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "B";
        }
    }

    public class OutputC
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "C";
        }
    }

    public class OutputFactory
    {
        public OutputB GenerateOutput(B foo)
        {
            return new OutputB();
        }

        public OutputC GenerateOutput(C foo)
        {
            return new OutputC();
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, I wish to print :

> B
>
> C

EDIT :
A working solution I found could be changing the item type to `dynamic`

```
foreach (dynamic item in list)
{
    DoSomething(factory.GenerateOutput(item));
}
```

I'm open to any better idea however. As pointed out in answer, the risk of runtime error after an evolution is great.

Comment: @DavidG I confess I was looking for an elegant pattern rather then reflection but if I don't find anything I would have to fall back to this indeed.

Comment: @DavidG : Changing the type of `item` in the `foreach` to `dynamic` solved the problem.

Comment: Like I tell people all the time (and even today!): Every time you use `dynamic`, a kitten dies. :)

Comment: @DavidG Isn't this a legitimate use case of dynamic ?

Comment: I'm not saying it isn't legitimate, but when I see dynamic, it's almost always a sign that your code is a bit screwy, it's a code smell.

Comment: @Baguette The fact that you've put yourself into the position where that's what you need to do is the problem.

Comment: @DavidG : After coming back to this topic after some time, I will choose the Visitor pattern solution that someone proposed I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler complains about your code because, as you pointed out, threre is no `GenerateOutput(SuperA)` in `OutputFactory` class and method call resolution happens at compile type, not at runtime, and therefore is based on the type of the reference (`item` is a reference with type `SuperA`) and not on the type of the runtime instance.

You can try with different approaches:

1. if you find it makes sense, you can try to move polymorphic behaviour (the output text to generate) into `SuperA` class hierarchy, adding an abstract method or property to `SuperA` and implementing it differently in `SuperA`'s subclasses

```
class SuperA {
  public abstract string Content { get; }
}

class B : SuperA {
  public string Content => "B";
}

class C : SuperA {
  public string Content => "C";
}

class Test {
  public void TestMethod() {
    // ...
    foreach (SuperA item in list) {
      Console.WriteLine(item.Content);
    }
}
```

Very simple but it does not work very well when `SuperA`,`B, and`C`classes are out of your control or when the different desired behaviours you should provide for`A`and`B`classes does not belong to`B`and`C` classes.

2. you can use an approach I like to call *set of responsibility*: it's something ilke the GoF's pattern *chain of responsibility* but without chain ;-); you can rewrite your `TestMethod` as follows:

```
public void TestMethod() {
    var list = new List<SuperA> {new B(), new C()};

    var compositeHandler = new CompositeHandler(new Handler[]  {
        new BHandler(),
        new CHandler()
    });

    foreach (SuperA item in list) {
      compositeHandler.Handle(item);
    }
}
```

So you need define a `Handler` interface and its implementations like follows:

```
interface Handler {
  bool CanHandle(SuperA item);

  void Handle(SuperA item);
}

class BHandler : Handler {
  bool CanHandle(SuperA item) => item is B;

  void Handle(SuperA item) {
   var b = (B)item; // cast here is safe due to previous check in `CanHandle()`
   DoSomethingUsingB(b);
  }
}

class CHandler : Handler {
  bool CanHandle(SuperA item) => item is C;

  void Handle(SuperA item) {
   var c = (C)item; // cast here is safe due to previous check in `CanHandle()`
   DoSomethingUsingC(c);
  }
}

class CompositeHandler {
  private readonly IEnumerable<handler> handlers;
  public CompositeHandler(IEnumerable<handler> handlers) {
    this.handlers = handlers;
  }

  public void Handle(SuperA item) {
    handlers.FirstOrDefault(h => h.CanHandle(item))?.Handle(item);
  }
}
```

This approach uses type checks (`item is B`), but hides them behind an interface (specifically, each implementation of the interface should provide a type check in order to select instances it can handle): if you need to add a third `D extends SuperA` subclass of your hierarchy root class you need only add a third `DHandler : Handler` implementation of `Handler` interface, without modify neither already provided implementations nor `CompositeHelper` class; the only change you should apply to existing code is the *registration* of the new `handler`'s implementation in the list you provide to `CompositeHelper`'s constructor, but this can easily be moved to you `IoC container` configuration or to an external configuration file.
I like this approach because it makes possibile to turn a *type check based* algorithm into a polymorphical one.

I wrote about this topic in a recent post on my technical blog: https://javapeanuts.blogspot.com/2018/10/set-of-responsibility.html.

3. You can approach the question through the GoF's *visitor* pattern, that is a bit more complicated than my suggested approach but was conceived precisely for such cases
4. You can adopt a `dynamic` based approach, as suggested in another response

I hope this can help you!

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive answer. I appreciate there is also a pre-.NET4 solution set of responsibility to this problem.

Comment: I wouldn't say the cast is safe in Handle method as it would be an exposed method and could be wrongly called without calling CanHandle by a future programmer.

Comment: Sure, you can add a guard in `Handle` implementation: the point IMHO is that the type check is hidden in specific interface implementations and does not pollute the main algorythm.

Comment: After thinking about it, leaving the topic for a while and coming back to it, I will choose the Visitor pattern implementation. As you said, it is precisely made for this, is self-documenting for other developers and doesn't rely on testing the types directly. Thank you for your comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can call it like this:

```
DoSomething((dynamic)factory.GenerateOutput((dynamic)item));
```

This way, using `dynamic` your objects will be binded at runtime to the correct methods.

With this implementation, you will have to take into consideration that you expose yourself to the risk of sending a `C` object for which no method was implemented and your code will still compile, but a runtime error will be generated.

Comment: I realized this and edited my original question right before reading your answer =) The risk is great indeed, I'll have carefull thoughts about this. Thanks ! 
I can simply use dynamic in the foreach though. Instead of casting twice as you showed me.